# Email alerts for drive failures

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, email

At our office, we're using a Windows 7 box as a file "server" for our accounting department. I have a spare drive in it that mirrors the accounting share for redundancy.

**Are there any utilities out there that could email me if one of the drives were to fail?** I've searched for related tools but most are server related utilities, not for workstations.

Drive failure is the only thing that concerns me, but notifications for other major system alerts would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a solution through **Spiceworks** which I'm already using.

Under Monitors & Alerts, I created a custom Alert:

**Type**: Physical Disk
**Name**: Disk Failure Prediction
**Condition**: Prediticted to Fail
**Applies** to: Computers
**Email**: Yes
**Enabled**: Yes

I'm not sure if this will email me for catastrohpic failure, however. If the disk crashes without first throwing a S.M.A.R.T. error, I believe it may not catch it. *The Spiceworks installation is actually hosted on this PC as well, so that may factor in.*